# Count hours figures and set a new day for every 7.5 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of training modules, each has a value for the number of hours it takes to train. For example:

**Training module One - 2.5 hours**
**Training module Two - 1.0 hours**
**....**

I have them set up as a jquery drag-drop, almost like a shopping cart so that users can grab the modules that want and drop them into another container.

When an item is added to the container, I need to work out what day of the training that module will be placed in. Each day is 7.5 hours.

What I need displayed in the drop container is this:

**Training module One   - 2.5 hours - Day 1**
**Training module Two   - 1.0 hours - Day 1**
**Training module Three - 4.0 hours - Day 1**
**Training module Four  - 1.0 hours - Day 2**
**Training module Five  - 4.5 hours - Day 2**
**Training module Six   - 3.0 hours - Day 3**
**....**

This is what I've tried:

```
var $dayFields = $('#sortable2 li').find('#day');
var $sumHrsFields = $('#sortable2 li').find('#sumHrs');

var hrsArray = $("#sortable2 li").find("#hrsSpan").map(function () { return $(this).text() }).get();            
//Add all the hrs together to get the total
for (var i in hrsArray) {
    total += hrsArray[i];
    if (total / 7.5 <= 1) {
        $($dayFields.get(i)).html('1');
        $($sumHrsFields.get(i)).html(total);
    }
    else if (total / 7.5 > 1) {
        dayText = total / 7.5;
        //if the dayText value ends up as a whole number, don't do anything. If it isn't, round down to whole number and add 1
        if (dayText % 1 == 0) {

        } 
        else {
            dayText = dayText | 0;
            dayText += 1; 
        }
        $($dayFields.get(i)).html(dayText);
        $($sumHrsFields.get(i)).html(total-(7.5));
    }
}
```

It works for the first 2 or 3 days but then the day values dont add up.

Is there a more elegant appoach to this? I feel like I'm overthinking the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is somehow sampler approach:

```js
var hrsArray = [1.75, 1, 3.25, 2.5];
var total = 0;
var hoursInDay = 7.5;
for (var i in hrsArray) {
  var moduleNo = parseInt(i) + 1;
  total += hrsArray[i];
  var days = Math.floor(total / hoursInDay);
  var dayText = days + 1; // need to add 1 for 1-day ahead

  $('#display').append('Module ' + moduleNo + ': ' + hrsArray[i] + ' hours, Day ' + dayText);
  $('#display').append('<br/>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display"/>
```

Comment: +1 for helpful, but the last added module for each day still seems to be wrong? When I add modules with hrs like this: **1.75**, **1**, **3.25**, **2.5** - all of them show the day as `1`

Comment: Updated day calculation logic

Comment: Thanks dude. This works for me with some modification to suit my app.